# Find node within a JSON object where "X" attribute equals to "xyz"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Following is my JSON object:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  var obj = {
    "cells": [{
      "type": "basic.Rect",
      "position": {
        "x": 320,
        "y": 140
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 54
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "021d1aef-72c7-4bff-b605-054bb5652ee3",
      "z": 1,
      "attrs": {
        "rect": {
          "fill": "transparent",
          "stroke": "#31d0c6",
          "width": 50,
          "height": 30,
          "rx": 2,
          "ry": 2,
          "stroke-width": 2,
          "stroke-dasharray": "0",
          "id": "",
          "compare": ""
        },
        "text": {
          "fill": "#c6c7e2",
          "text": "rect",
          "font-size": 11,
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0
        },
        ".": {
          "data-tooltip-position": "left",
          "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Rect",
      "position": {
        "x": 550,
        "y": 120
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 54
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "b230e76b-aa4d-4cf7-8cee-16dc3161fc75",
      "z": 2,
      "attrs": {
        "rect": {
          "fill": "transparent",
          "stroke": "#31d0c6",
          "width": 50,
          "height": 30,
          "rx": 2,
          "ry": 2,
          "stroke-width": 2,
          "stroke-dasharray": "0",
          "id": "",
          "compare": ""
        },
        "text": {
          "fill": "#c6c7e2",
          "text": "rect",
          "font-size": 11,
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0
        },
        ".": {
          "data-tooltip-position": "left",
          "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Text",
      "position": {
        "x": 320,
        "y": 300
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 45
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "d692f3ff-8b17-4c8a-8c80-980e0e12047c",
      "z": 3,
      "attrs": {
        "text": {
          "font-size": 20,
          "fill": "#7cbd31",
          "text": "vrn",
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0,
          "id": ""
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Text",
      "position": {
        "x": 460,
        "y": 300
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 45
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "fb60eb9f-2f97-41dc-8b1c-4da6dffab9ab",
      "z": 4,
      "attrs": {
        "text": {
          "font-size": 20,
          "fill": "#7cbd31",
          "text": "vrnvalue",
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0,
          "id": "vrn"
        }
      }
    }]
  };
```

I want to find the node which has `id` attribute = "vrn" and change it's `text` attribute value from `vrvalue` to `123`

I tried :

```
jQuery.each(obj, function(i,ob) {
   jQuery.each(ob, function(i1,ob1) {
    jQuery.each(ob1, function(i2,ob2) {
    console.log(ob2);
  });
  });
```

But, I feel lost now.

Comment: will someone atleast explain why this question has been downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through a number of cells object and if the id is vrn, change it to 123 or something else.

```
if(obj.cells[i].attrs.text.id=='vrn'){
   obj.cells[i].attrs.text.id='123';
}
```

```js
var obj = {
    "cells": [{
      "type": "basic.Rect",
      "position": {
        "x": 320,
        "y": 140
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 54
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "021d1aef-72c7-4bff-b605-054bb5652ee3",
      "z": 1,
      "attrs": {
        "rect": {
          "fill": "transparent",
          "stroke": "#31d0c6",
          "width": 50,
          "height": 30,
          "rx": 2,
          "ry": 2,
          "stroke-width": 2,
          "stroke-dasharray": "0",
          "id": "",
          "compare": ""
        },
        "text": {
          "fill": "#c6c7e2",
          "text": "rect",
          "font-size": 11,
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0
        },
        ".": {
          "data-tooltip-position": "left",
          "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Rect",
      "position": {
        "x": 550,
        "y": 120
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 54
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "b230e76b-aa4d-4cf7-8cee-16dc3161fc75",
      "z": 2,
      "attrs": {
        "rect": {
          "fill": "transparent",
          "stroke": "#31d0c6",
          "width": 50,
          "height": 30,
          "rx": 2,
          "ry": 2,
          "stroke-width": 2,
          "stroke-dasharray": "0",
          "id": "",
          "compare": ""
        },
        "text": {
          "fill": "#c6c7e2",
          "text": "rect",
          "font-size": 11,
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0
        },
        ".": {
          "data-tooltip-position": "left",
          "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Text",
      "position": {
        "x": 320,
        "y": 300
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 45
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "d692f3ff-8b17-4c8a-8c80-980e0e12047c",
      "z": 3,
      "attrs": {
        "text": {
          "font-size": 20,
          "fill": "#7cbd31",
          "text": "vrn",
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0,
          "id": ""
        }
      }
    }, {
      "type": "basic.Text",
      "position": {
        "x": 460,
        "y": 300
      },
      "size": {
        "width": 90,
        "height": 45
      },
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "fb60eb9f-2f97-41dc-8b1c-4da6dffab9ab",
      "z": 4,
      "attrs": {
        "text": {
          "font-size": 20,
          "fill": "#7cbd31",
          "text": "vrnvalue",
          "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
          "font-weight": "Normal",
          "stroke-width": 0,
          "id": "vrn"
        }
      }
    }]
  };
  var len=obj.cells.length;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
       if(obj.cells[i].attrs.text.id=='vrn'){
          obj.cells[i].attrs.text.id='123';
       }
  }
  console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm not even sure I completely understand what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: What I understood is, he wants to find id containing 'vrn' value and change its value to 123 from given JSON data.

Comment: May you add the explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var cells = obj.cells.map(function (cell) {
    if (cell.attrs.text.id === "vrn" ) {
        cell.attrs.text.text = "123"
    }
    return cell
});
```

```js
var obj = {
    "cells": [{
        "type": "basic.Rect",
        "position": {
            "x": 320,
            "y": 140
        },
        "size": {
            "width": 90,
            "height": 54
        },
        "angle": 0,
        "id": "021d1aef-72c7-4bff-b605-054bb5652ee3",
        "z": 1,
        "attrs": {
            "rect": {
                "fill": "transparent",
                "stroke": "#31d0c6",
                "width": 50,
                "height": 30,
                "rx": 2,
                "ry": 2,
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "stroke-dasharray": "0",
                "id": "",
                "compare": ""
            },
            "text": {
                "fill": "#c6c7e2",
                "text": "rect",
                "font-size": 11,
                "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
                "font-weight": "Normal",
                "stroke-width": 0
            },
            ".": {
                "data-tooltip-position": "left",
                "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "basic.Rect",
        "position": {
            "x": 550,
            "y": 120
        },
        "size": {
            "width": 90,
            "height": 54
        },
        "angle": 0,
        "id": "b230e76b-aa4d-4cf7-8cee-16dc3161fc75",
        "z": 2,
        "attrs": {
            "rect": {
                "fill": "transparent",
                "stroke": "#31d0c6",
                "width": 50,
                "height": 30,
                "rx": 2,
                "ry": 2,
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "stroke-dasharray": "0",
                "id": "",
                "compare": ""
            },
            "text": {
                "fill": "#c6c7e2",
                "text": "rect",
                "font-size": 11,
                "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
                "font-weight": "Normal",
                "stroke-width": 0
            },
            ".": {
                "data-tooltip-position": "left",
                "data-tooltip-position-selector": ".joint-stencil"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "basic.Text",
        "position": {
            "x": 320,
            "y": 300
        },
        "size": {
            "width": 90,
            "height": 45
        },
        "angle": 0,
        "id": "d692f3ff-8b17-4c8a-8c80-980e0e12047c",
        "z": 3,
        "attrs": {
            "text": {
                "font-size": 20,
                "fill": "#7cbd31",
                "text": "vrn",
                "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
                "font-weight": "Normal",
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "id": ""
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "basic.Text",
        "position": {
            "x": 460,
            "y": 300
        },
        "size": {
            "width": 90,
            "height": 45
        },
        "angle": 0,
        "id": "fb60eb9f-2f97-41dc-8b1c-4da6dffab9ab",
        "z": 4,
        "attrs": {
            "text": {
                "font-size": 20,
                "fill": "#7cbd31",
                "text": "vrnvalue",
                "font-family": "Roboto Condensed",
                "font-weight": "Normal",
                "stroke-width": 0,
                "id": "vrn"
            }
        }
    }]
};

var obj.cells = obj.cells.map(function (cell) {
    if (cell.attrs.text.id === "vrn" ) {
        cell.attrs.text.text = "123"
    }
    return cell
});



console.log(obj.cells[cells.length -1].attrs.text.text); // 123
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
obj.cells.filter(function(rm){if(rm.attrs.text.id == "vrn"){
     return rm.attrs.text.text = 123
} })

console.log(obj)
```